# How to create horizontal menubar with submenu MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, menubar

I want to create Horizontal menu bar with submenu I had tried many but I didn't get it.

I had tried with hoverIntent.js but how to call this into MVC4 that is I don't know.

Thank you,
-Jitendra Jadav.

Comment: please specify what you have done until now, and show some effort

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/02/CSS-Control-Adapter-Toolkit-for-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx

Comment: http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and install this package from nuget package manager `Bootstrap for mvc 4`.
It turns your default layout to something like this
[image]

And it is very easy to customize your menu bar, and add child menu to it.
Hope it'll help to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was also in search of similar menu bar which you are seeking for, after lots of Googling I found it out, hope the below code will help you.

In your **_Layout.cshtml** put following code:

`

```
<ul class="menuTemplate4 decor4_1">
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
 <li class="separator"></li>                     
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
 <li class="separator"></li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
 <li class="separator"></li>                          
  <li><a href="#" class="arrow">Reports</a>
  <div class="drop decor4_2">
  <div>
   <a href="#">Reports 1</a><br />
   <a href="#">Reports 2</a><br />
   <a href="#">Reports 3</a><br />
   </div>
  </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

`

Add below code in your **Site.css**:

```
   .menuTemplate4
{

    margin: 0 auto; width: auto;float:left;   
    position:relative;
    z-index:4;
    height: 36px;
    background: #2777A3 url(bg.gif);
    border: 1px solid #036;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
    .menuTemplate4 li
{
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    z-index:5;
}
.menuTemplate4 li:hover, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover
{
    border-top:1px solid #CC0000;
}

.menuTemplate4 a
{
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}
.menuTemplate4 li:hover a, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover a
{
    background-color: #80CBF0;
    color: #000;    
    z-index: 9;
}
.menuTemplate4 a.arrow
{
    background: url(arrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
}

.menuTemplate4 li.menuRight
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.menuTemplate4 li.separator
{
    display:none;
}

.menuTemplate4 .drop
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:5;
    left: -9999px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom:3px solid #990000;
    background: #FFF;            
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;  
    color:#0F4F89;
    top:34px;              
}

.menuTemplate4 .drop a
{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;    
    position: static;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image:none;
}

.menuTemplate4 li:hover .drop, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover .drop
{
    left: 1px;
    background:#DAF0FE url(bg-right.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    width:62px;
}
.menuTemplate4 li:hover .dropToLeft, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover .dropToLeft
{
    left: auto;
    right: -1px;
    background:white url(bg-left.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
}
.menuTemplate4 li:hover .dropToLeft2, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover .dropToLeft2
{
    left: auto;
    right: -60px;
}

.menuTemplate4 div.drop div div
{
    padding: 6px 20px;
}
.menuTemplate4 li:hover .drop a, .menuTemplate4 li.onhover .drop a
{
    background: none;
    background-image:none;
    padding:0 0;
}
.menuTemplate4 div.drop div a
{
    line-height: 24px;  
    color: #0F4F89;
    background:none;
}
.menuTemplate4 div.drop div a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:Red;
}

.menuTemplate4 div.left {float:left;}

.decor4_1 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #999;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #999;

}

.decor4_2 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #CCC;  
}
```

Enjoy!!!!!